# Angular - Set ng-model using scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

Is this something one should not do? As I am unable to get it to work.

In my controller I have

```
$scope.test = "someValue"
```

and in my view

```
<input ng-model="test" />
```

What I am expecting to occur

```
<input ng-model="someValue" />
```

However, ng-model stays as being set to "test".

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What is the attribute that you want to set ? or is it that text value be "someValue"?

Answer (score 3):

That's not the way `ng-model` works. If you have a scope variable, as in your case `test` and value of this variable will reflect in the value property of your `input`. This means that `someValue` will be visible in the `input`. In other words: `ng-model` is a directive that binds to, e.g. an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using the `NgModelController`.

> NgModelController provides API for the ngModel directive. The
>   controller contains services for data-binding, validation, CSS
>   updates, and value formatting and parsing

Here is an example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('TestController', TestController);

function TestController() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.myModel = "This is the model value";
  vm.selectedOption = undefined;

  vm.options = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Option A'
  }, {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Option B'
  }, {
    id: '3',
    name: 'Option C'
  }];
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestController as vm">
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.myModel" />

  <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" ng-model="vm.selectedOption">
    <option ng-repeat="option in vm.options" value="{{option.id}}">{{ option.name }}</option>
  </select>
  
  <pre ng-if="vm.selectedOption">Selected Option: {{ vm.selectedOption }}</pre>
</body>
```

The example above also shows some best practices, means using `controllerAs` syntax for your view and a clear declaration of your controller signature.

Comment: Thank you, I am always on the lookout for tips for best practices. I can get this to work for a simple input in my view but not for the one I want.  I think the issue I am having is I am trying to set the ng-model of a <select> which is using the chosen plugin, and which is also a tabbed view.

Comment: Updated my example above for your needs. Now you can check the `<select>`.

Answer (score 0):

Show your controller code. However, I have demonstrated below that it should work.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = "somevalue";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <form ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="test" />
  </form>
</body>
```

`ng-model` just represents the binding object. It will not change. What changes is the `value`, which corresponds to the value that the `ng-model` object takes on.